# SVN Update fails to add new files

Tags: linux, macos, svn, terminal, svn-update

Whenever i do an `svn up` it updates all files in the main directory but skips all files in sub directories.

Also it fails to add new files, thus if there is a new file "**newFile**", doing an

```
svn up
```

does not add the file but

```
svn up newFile
```

adds the file correctly. How do i fix my svn ?

Comment: What's your working copy depth? It sounds like it's not fully recursive.

Answer (score 0):

You can make SVN update non-recursively by using this command:

```
svn update --depth=files
```

The `--depth` argument can take the following parameters: empty, files, immediates or infinity